# What do I do about a VERY MOLDY dishwasher air gap?

Tags: mold

Just moved to a new place a few months ago and there is TONS of mold in the dishwasher air gap. Ive never had one before so I never thought to look inside to see what it was. I recently went to the doctor for breathing problems and she asked if I was exposed to mold. How do I clean it? could this mold be harming my health and is it getting mold in my dishwasher when I run it? thanks for any advice!

Comment: If it's in the air gap I'd bet it's all along the hose and there may be other issues. Air gaps aren't that expensive. Don't bother cleaning. replace. Go for replacing drain hose too. If landlord won't do it you may be able to do it and subtract from your rent with his permission depending on the laws where you live. Might help to have doctor indicate you could have a problem with mold. It's possible the dishwasher backed up and there could be more mold elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take it apart and clean it with bleach water.  Most are usually designed for regular maintenance, bits of garbage can get pumped through there and may build up.

If this is a rental, I would ask my maintenance personnel to handle the issue, you might put yourself at liability if you reassemble it wrong and cause water damage.

Furthermore, I cannot say it would be causing you health issues.  But if you have a healthy immune system, it is highly unlikely the small amount of mold in the kitchen is dangerous.  Unless you are breathing regularly over the air-gap.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I do not know how to take it apart so I would have to ask the landlord (who isn't helpful). it is actually a large amount- it is coming out up through the opening of the air gap so who knows how much is in the plumbing. Is the air gap directly connected to the dishwasher, could the mold be flowing through the dishwasher? I want to stop using our dishes if so. Thanks!

Comment: The air gap is for just waste water and unlikely to contact your dishes if there is mold in the waste line, which is unlikely as well.  A few run would clear or kill any present.